# Python unittest - exit if it tests an program with infinite loop

Tags: python, infinite-loop, python-unittest

I want to test some function with Python Unittest. If my program has an infinite loop I dont know how to exit that test.
I tried with timeout-decorator and wrapt-timeout-decorator, but neither of those worked. I want a solution in Windows.
Maybe I have to kill the process that handles the unittesting, what do you think?

Comment: In general I think that responsibility should belong to the thing running the unit tests, not in the unit tests themselves.

Comment: I've solved it with subprocess.run and timeout. If you have other better solution, I'd be glad.

Answer (score 0):

Here we are!
Here the two tests passes (test_loop_infinite and test_loop_finite)

Ask for any questions:

```
import unittest
import time
import threading
import ctypes


def my_fct(param):
    print("Start my loop function")
    if param:
        print("Params make my function is infinite loop")
        while True:
            print("Looping...")
            time.sleep(1)
    else:
        print("Params make my function return")
        return


def terminate_thread(thread):
    exc = ctypes.py_object(SystemExit)
    res = ctypes.pythonapi.PyThreadState_SetAsyncExc(
        ctypes.c_long(thread.ident), exc)
    if res == 0:
        raise ValueError("nonexistent thread id")
    elif res > 1:
        ctypes.pythonapi.PyThreadState_SetAsyncExc(thread.ident, None)
        raise SystemError("PyThreadState_SetAsyncExc failed")

class Test(unittest.TestCase):
    def raise_loop(self, timeout, fct, args):
        x = threading.Thread(target=fct, args=args)
        t0 = time.time()
        x.start()
        time.sleep(timeout)
        if x.is_alive():
            terminate_thread(x)
            raise Exception("TimeOut loop")

    def test_loop_infinite(self):
        with self.assertRaises(Exception):
            self.raise_loop(2, my_fct, (True, ))

    def test_loop_finite(self):
        self.raise_loop(2, my_fct, (False, ))
    

if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```